# Get fields from one column to another in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Below i have a table where i need to get fields from one column to three columns.

This is how i would like the data to end up

Column1
Music

Column2
com.sec.android.app.music

Column3
com.sec.android.app.music.MusicActionTabActivity

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Give the table a numeric autonumber id
2. Remove the rows with no data with a select where blank spaces or null
3. Find records with no point in the content with a select
4. Use the previous query as a source and use the id to find the id + 1 to find the next record and do   the same with + 2 to find the second row
5. Build a table to hold the new structure and use the query as a source to insert the new created data in the new table with the 3 columns structure.

This is an example using sql server

**Test table design**

[image]

**Data in table**

[image]

**Query**

Look at the query from the inside. The first query inside clean the null records. Then the second query find the records with out point. This records are the reference to find the related two records. Then the id of the records with out point are used to make a query in the select adding 1 for the next record and then other query adding 2 to find the other record. Now you only need to create a table to insert this data, using this query as the source.

[image]

Comment: How would the query look for step 4? made it that far. thanks for you help

Comment: Hi Bignadad, the query is next to the paragraph below the query header. The first 7 rows in the screen shot. The next two lines are for get a result of the raw data and make a comparison.